# Update live table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

After populating the `stock_tmp` table, i'm running these SQL queries via legacy `mysqli` wrapper code. I don't think this code needs additional locks to prevent people from seeing incorrect data. Is that correct?

```
DELETE FROM stock WHERE ean NOT IN (SELECT ean FROM stock_tmp);
REPLACE INTO stock SELECT * FROM stock_tmp;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO stock SELECT * FROM stock_tmp AS tmp
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ean=tmp.ean, etc=tmp.etc;
```

Is 10+% faster than `REPLACE INTO` and does not change all `AUTO_INCREMENT` data. [Source.](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/replace-into-think-twice)

10+ times faster is this:

```
RENAME TABLE stock TO stock_swp,
stock_tmp TO stock,
stock_swp TO stock_tmp;
```

The implied locking should be sufficient in any case.